# Правильно ли реализован паттерн Builder ?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

**Здравствуйте !!!**

Недавно, я приступил к изучению паттернов проектирования. Один из самых первых паттернов, который был реализован - это Builder. Какие у Вас есть замечания по данной реализации. **Заранее спасибо !** 
***Исходный код:***

1) Абстрактный класс `BaseCarBuilder`.

```
public abstract class BaseCarBuilder {
    public abstract void buildCategory(CategoryCar pCategoryCar);
    public abstract void buildCarcass(CarcassType pCarcassType) ;
    public abstract void buildEngine(Engine pEngine);
    public abstract void buildColorCarcass(ColorCar pColorCar) ;
    public abstract void buildDoors(int pDoors) ;
    public Car getBuiltCar() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

2) Класс Car.

```
public class Car {

    public final static int TWO_DOORS = 2;
    public final static int THREE_DOORS = 3;
    public final static int FOUR_DOORS = 4;
    public final static int FIVE_DOORS = 5;

    private int doorsCount;

    private Engine engine;
    private String carName;
    private ColorCar colorCar;
    private CarcassType carcassType;
    private CategoryCar categoryCar;

    public Car(String pCarName) {

        this.carName = pCarName;
    }

    public ColorCar getColorCar() {
        return colorCar;
    }

    public void setColorCar(ColorCar colorCar) {
        this.colorCar = colorCar;
    }

    public CarcassType getCarcassType() {
        return carcassType;
    }

    public void setCarcassType(CarcassType carcassType) {
        this.carcassType = carcassType;
    }

    public CategoryCar getCategoryCar() {
        return categoryCar;
    }

    public void setCategoryCar(CategoryCar categoryCar) {
        this.categoryCar = categoryCar;
    }

    public int getDoorsCount() {
        return doorsCount;
    }

    public void setDoorsCount(int doorsCount) {
        this.doorsCount = doorsCount;
    }

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public String getCarInfo() {

        String info =
                "car name = " + carName
                        + " *** category car = " + categoryCar
                        + " *** carcass tape = " + carcassType
                        + " *** engine = " + engine
                        + " *** color = " + colorCar
                        + " *** count doors = " + doorsCount;
        System.err.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        return info;
    }
}
```

3) Класс `MersedesBenzBuilder`, который наследуется от `BaseCarBuilder`.

```
public class MersedesBenzBuilder extends BaseCarBuilder {

    private Car car;

    public MersedesBenzBuilder() {

        car = new Car("Mersedes Benz");
    }

    @Override
    public void buildCategory(CategoryCar pCategoryCar) {

        car.setCategoryCar(pCategoryCar);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildCarcass(CarcassType pCarcassType) {

        car.setCarcassType(pCarcassType);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildDoors(int pDoors) {

        car.setDoorsCount(pDoors);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildEngine(Engine pEngine) {

        car.setEngine(pEngine);
    }

    @Override
    public void buildColorCarcass(ColorCar pColorCar) {

        car.setColorCar(pColorCar);
    }
}
```

4) Есть класс Директор (Диспетчер).

```
public class Director {

    public Car buildNewCar(BaseCarBuilder carBuilder, CategoryCar pCategoryCar,
                           CarcassType pCarcassType, int pDoors, Engine pEngine, ColorCar pColorCar) {

        Car tempCar = null;

        if (carBuilder != null) {

            carBuilder.buildCategory(pCategoryCar);
            carBuilder.buildCarcass(pCarcassType);
            carBuilder.buildDoors(pDoors);
            carBuilder.buildEngine(pEngine);
            carBuilder.buildColorCarcass(pColorCar);
            tempCar = carBuilder.getBuiltCar();

        } else {

            final String nullPoint = "Yoa are not create car_builder";
            Exception exception = new NullPointerException(nullPoint);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempCar;
    }
}

5) Класс который запускает этот паттерн RunBuilderPattern.

public class RunBuilderPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car car = null;
        Director director = new Director();

        MersedesBenzBuilder mersedesBenzBuilder = new MersedesBenzBuilder();

        car = director.buildNewCar(
                mersedesBenzBuilder,
                CategoryCar.SPORT_CAR,
                CarcassType.CABRIOLET,
                Car.TWO_DOORS, Engine.PETROL,
                ColorCar.RED);

        System.out.println("CAR INFO: " + car.getCarInfo());
    }
}
```

6) Дополнительные классы, точнее Enum-ы:

```
public enum CarcassType {

    SEDAN, UNIVERSAL, CABRIOLET, HATCHBACK, COUPE, LIMOUSINE
}

public enum CategoryCar {

    CARGO, PASSENGER, BUS, SPORT_CAR
}

public enum ColorCar {

    BLACK, WHITE, RED, GREEN, BLUE, ORANGE, BROWN
}

public enum Engine {

    DIZEL, PETROL, GAZ, HUBRID
}
```

7) Вот что выводится в консоль:

```
CAR INFO: car name = Mersedes Benz *** category car = SPORT_CAR *** carcass tape = CABRIOLET *** engine = PETROL *** color = RED *** count doors = 2
```

**Жду Ваших замечаний, советов, ругани и брани !!!**

Comment: Не понимаю смысла ругать чей-то код. Многие(в том числе и я) пишут иногда код криво, неправильно, некрасиво, но это не причина его бранить. При чём этот процесс не принесёт никому пользу.

Comment: ок, понял!

Comment: >При чём этот процесс не принесёт никому пользу

в этом есть смысл, если критика конструктивна. Не "ты му**к, а код твой - г**но", а "в вашем коде есть следующие недостатки: 

1) <% подробное_описание_1-го_недостатка %> 

2) <% подробное_описание_2-го_недостатка %> ... 

n) <% подробное_описание_n-го_недостатка %>"

А вот умалчивание о недостатках "по доброте душевной" - это нечто из серии, когда благими намерениями устлана дорога в ад. Если человек не знает о недостатках своего кода, он их и не исправит

Comment: какие у Вас есть замечания по данному коду ?

Comment: никаких, я его не смотрел - просто не дошли руки, да и Java для меня не родной язык, хотя я "говорю" на одном ее близком родственнике))

Comment: если будет желание и время, посмотрите код. Может что-то подскажите, как родственник !!!

Comment: Я бы заметил, что красная спортивная двухдверная машина — это не мерс, это Феррари.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это древний code review запрос без контекста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всегда пожалуйста:

```
public abstract class BaseCarBuilder {

    // Мне почему-то кажется, что для примера можно было обойтись двумя-тремя  
    // методами вида buildSomething. Ваш текущий код — это один большой
    // boilerplate, где из-за геттеров и сеттеров теряется смысл.
    public abstract void buildCategory(CategoryCar pCategoryCar);

    // Carcass — крайне неудачный термин. См. http://goo.gl/SCMO1q
    public abstract void buildCarcass(CarcassType pCarcassType) ;

    // Параметры с именами вида pSomething не следуют naming convention.
    // Если бы вы, кстати, инвертировали слова в именах вида pColorCar ---->
    // carColor (или просто color), уже стало бы лучше и понятнее.
    // pCategoryCar в текущем варианте означает что-то в духе "машина с
    // какой-то там категорией", а используется в значении "категория машины".
    public abstract void buildEngine(Engine pEngine);

    // Опять-таки, плывет нейминг. В текущем варианте по названиям методов
    // получается, что ваш builder можно попросить сделать "просто carcass", а
    // можно "цветной carcass". Почему бы не объединить buildColorCarcass и
    // buildCarcass в один метод или просто сделать buildCarcass + buildColor?
    public abstract void buildColorCarcass(ColorCar pColorCar) ;

    // Эти замечания — не очень принципиальные. См. ниже.
    public abstract void buildDoors(int pDoors) ;

    public Car getBuiltCar() {
        return null;
    }

public class Car {
    // public final static int TWENTY_ELEVEN_DOORS = 2011. Почему не enum?
    public final static int TWO_DOORS = 2;
    public final static int THREE_DOORS = 3;
    public final static int FOUR_DOORS = 4;
    public final static int FIVE_DOORS = 5;

    private int doorsCount;

    private Engine engine;
    private String carName;
    private ColorCar colorCar;
    private CarcassType carcassType;
    private CategoryCar categoryCar;

    public Car(String pCarName) {

        this.carName = pCarName;
    }

    public ColorCar getColorCar() {
        return colorCar;
    }

    ....

    public Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }

    public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    // Погодите, а не 'toString' ли это, часом? Вы, кстати, задумались над тем,
    // что, если написать в *произвольном* месте кода вот это,
    //
    // [[[
    // String info = car.getCarInfo();
    // info = car.getCarInfo();
    // info = car.getCarInfo();
    // ......
    // info = car.getCarInfo();
    // ]]]
    //
    // то ваш stderr окажется зафлужен строчками вида "------------------"?

    public String getCarInfo() {

        String info =
                "car name = " + carName
                        + " *** category car = " + categoryCar
                        + " *** carcass tape = " + carcassType
                        + " *** engine = " + engine
                        + " *** color = " + colorCar
                        + " *** count doors = " + doorsCount;
        System.err.println("---------------------------------------------------");
        return info;
    }
}

public class MersedesBenzBuilder extends BaseCarBuilder {

    private Car car;

    public MersedesBenzBuilder() {

        car = new Car("Mersedes Benz");
    }

    @Override
    public void buildCategory(CategoryCar pCategoryCar) {

        car.setCategoryCar(pCategoryCar);
    }

    ....

    @Override
    public void buildColorCarcass(ColorCar pColorCar) {

        car.setColorCar(pColorCar);
    }
}

public class Director {

    public Car buildNewCar(BaseCarBuilder carBuilder, CategoryCar pCategoryCar,
                           CarcassType pCarcassType, int pDoors, Engine pEngine,
                           ColorCar pColorCar) {

        // Вот, теперь к главному. Вы неправильно поняли Builder по Gang of
        // Four, и поэтому получилась чушь. При изучении паттернов один из самых
        // важных принципов, как бы банально это не звучало, заключается в том,
        // чтобы *четко* следовать тому, что написано. Давайте внимательно
        // посмотрим на UML-диаграмму для паттерна Builder (http://goo.gl/rX9gMN).
        // Сколько параметров у метода Director.construct? Один. А у вас сколько?
        // Сколько параметров у метода Builder.buildPart? Ноль. А у вас сколько?
        // А что это значит? Правильно, что вы неверно истолковали суть этого
        // паттерна.

        // В паттерне Builder важен следующий инвариант: как только объект
        // ConcreteBuilder создан, он более не допускает параметризации извне.
        // Идея заключается в том, что конкретный экземпляр Builder умеет
        // каким-то своим способом совершать "маленькие шажки" к созданию
        // объекта (buildPart), а Director умеет объединять шажки из интерфейса
        // Builder таким образом, чтобы получился объект.

        // Конкретно в вашем случае детали типа Engine.PETROL и
        // CategoryCar.SPORT_CAR должны были быть "зашиты" в реализации класса
        // MersedesBenzBuilder. А у вас получилась такая штука, что вы вместо
        // Builder'a сделали крайне неочевидный named constructor, который
        // весело перебрасывает аргументы туда-сюда.

        // Годную реализацию этого паттерна на Java можете посмотреть здесь —
        // http://goo.gl/KRk1L
        // Также рекомендую вам ознакомиться с паттерном Fluent Builder —
        // http://goo.gl/HIulBb

        // И да, паттерны обычно тем или иным способом решают какую-то
        // прикладную задачу. Поэтому "приступать к изучению паттернов," не
        // имея под рукой хорошей задачи — это довольно плохая идея. Придумайте
        // себе хорошую задачу и пытайтесь применять паттерны для ее решения, а
        // не придумывайте задачи, чтобы применить паттерны.

        // Хороший пример такой задачи как раз и приводится в книге GoF
        // (http://www.amazon.com/dp/0201633612), где они step-by-step
        // разрабатывают текстовый редактор.

        Car tempCar = null;

        if (carBuilder != null) {

            carBuilder.buildCategory(pCategoryCar);
            carBuilder.buildCarcass(pCarcassType);
            carBuilder.buildDoors(pDoors);
            carBuilder.buildEngine(pEngine);
            carBuilder.buildColorCarcass(pColorCar);

            // Я, кстати, вообще не понимаю, как это может работать, поскольку
            // в вашем коде метод getBuiltCar всегда возвращает null.
            tempCar = carBuilder.getBuiltCar();

        } else {
            // Простите, здесь у меня просто глаза вытекли.
            final String nullPoint = "Yoa are not create car_builder";
            Exception exception = new NullPointerException(nullPoint);
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tempCar;
    }
}

// Какое сказочное название для класса :)
public class RunBuilderPattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car car = null;
        Director director = new Director();

        MersedesBenzBuilder mersedesBenzBuilder = new MersedesBenzBuilder();

        // Ух ты! Смотрите! Я на самом деле работаю как простой конструктор,
        // но два раза разворачиваю и заворачиваю параметры.
        car = director.buildNewCar(
                mersedesBenzBuilder,
                CategoryCar.SPORT_CAR,
                CarcassType.CABRIOLET,
                Car.TWO_DOORS, Engine.PETROL,
                ColorCar.RED);

        System.out.println("CAR INFO: " + car.getCarInfo());
    }
}

// ... а вот эти штуки неплохо бы переместить в класс Car.
public enum CarcassType {

    SEDAN, UNIVERSAL, CABRIOLET, HATCHBACK, COUPE, LIMOUSINE
}

public enum CategoryCar {

    CARGO, PASSENGER, BUS, SPORT_CAR
}

public enum ColorCar {

    BLACK, WHITE, RED, GREEN, BLUE, ORANGE, BROWN
}

public enum Engine {

    DIZEL, PETROL, GAZ, HUBRID
}
```

Comment: Огромное - Огромное спасибо за такой конструктивный ответ и замечания по делу !!!
Буду стараться исправлять свои ошибки и недочеты.

Comment: Жду еще кода на ревью :) Можете, кстати, исправить все проблемы в этом коде и прилепить патч, чтобы на него можно было посмотреть. Это обычно даже полезнее, чем переписывать что-то from scratch.

Comment: Постарался исправить Ваши замечания. Решил Выложить код на GitHub,если Вы не возражаете. Вот ссылка: https://github.com/javaAndroidCode/BuilderPattern

Comment: @Иван_Белозеров0011 Сделайте, пожалуйста отдельный вопрос для новой версии (я хотел бы написать подробный ответ, а не комментарий). Можете указать текущий вопрос как related. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: По Вашей просьбе,выложил на рассмотрение исправленную версию паттерна Builder. http://hashcode.ru/questions/253372/java-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD-builder-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5